# (limit of) a linear second order recurrence relation with variable coefficients

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence relation:

$(n + 1) a_{n + 2} = (w (n + 1) - c) a_{n + 1} - z (n + 1)*a_{n}$

that I would like to either solve, or to get the $n$ goes to Infinity limit of the ratio $a_n/b_n$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ satisfy that same recurrence relation above, but with different initial conditions: $a_0=0$, $a_1=z$, $b_0=1$, $b_1=w-c/2$.

Problem is that I am a physicist and never learned how to do this sort of thing. I have been reading posts on the recurrence equations for the past few days, tried the Hyper algorithm from A=B book (no solutions found), and looked through lists of special functions in the hopes of finding one that looks right (nothing so far). Can anyone please tell me if there are any tricks that will give me the limit of $a_n/b_n$ that I need without solving for $a_n$ and $b_n$? Or point me in the right direction as far as solving that recurrence relation goes?

Comment: http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/1-4/jeske-a.pdf is the only resource I have found on variable coefficient recurrence relations.

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$:

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 1) a_{n + 2} z^n
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} w(n + 1) a_{n + 1} z^n - c \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
       - \sum_{n \ge 0} z(n) a_n z^n
$$

Recognize some sums: $\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n = \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2}$,
also $\sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n z^n = z \frac{d}{d z} A(z)$. As long as your $w(n)$ and $z(n)$ are polynomials, this will dispatch them. If they are powers of a constant, it gets hairier, but perhaps doable. The result will be a differential/functional equation for $A(z)$. From the function (even if it is a mess) a lot can be learned about the asymptotics of coefficients. A thorough treatment is by Flajolet and Sedgewick ["Analytic Combinatorics"](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf).